# Can't find 'apksigner' executable to manually sign APK

Tags: android, apk, apksigner

Following the [Sign Your App Manually](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually) guide,

> You can sign your app from the command line using standard tools from the Android SDK and the JDK

I should have `apksigner` somewhere to run

> $ apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.jks my-app.apk

Where is this executable supposed to be? The documentation never specifies where I'm supposed to get the tool on the Signing guide or the [apksigner](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner.html) doc.

I don't recall having this problem last time I manually signed an app. I've searched all the directories I can think of with no luck (including subdirectories):

- AppData\Local\Android\sdk
- Program Files\Android\Android Studio
- Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

[Googling for 'apksigner'](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=apksigner) just seems to turn up a number of unofficial apk signing tools but no official download. What am I missing?

Running Android Studio 2.2, Build Tools 24.0.2, JDK 1.8

Thanks

**ANSWERED:** Updating to to 24.0.3 solves it. Thanks to [Alex Klyubin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5818824/alex-klyubin), please upvote his answer. For some reason Build Tools 24.0.2 simply does not have apksigner.

> Build Tools, Revision 24.0.3 (September 2016)
>
> - Added apksigner, an APK signing tool to replace jarsigner ...

Comment: Re: apksigner not there in 24.0.2. apksigner is a new tool. It didn't yet exist when Android SDK Build Tools 24.0.2 were released.

Comment: Did you run that command inside Android Studio? When I run the command it says apksigner command not found. Do I need to set enviornment variable ? @ScottyC

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`apksigner` shipped with Android SDK Build Tools 24.0.3 (see https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html). The tool can be found in the Android SDK's `build-tools/<tools version>` directory. For example, `build-tools/24.0.3/apksigner` on Linux/OSX and `build-tools/24.0.3/apksigner.bat` on Windows.

Comment: Note that `apksigner` is missing in version `26.0.0` of build-tools. It is tracked in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62696222 and supposed to be fixed in the next version. The workaround until then is to use `apksigner` from `25.0.3`.

Comment: I just found out this as well, very annoying. I wonder how `26.0.0` passed the tests for release

Comment: downloading 26.0.1 via the android studio sdk manager fixes this. my Ubuntu path: /home/__user__/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.1/apksigner

Comment: ugh, I thought I was losing my mind; thanks for pointing out the missing tool in 26.0.0. How is that google keeps having these problems with missing <whatever> from sdk versions? If I had a nickel for every time this has happened...

Answer (score 20):

On mac 
The Apksigner is inside build tools all you need is this line

```
/Users/adewale***/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/apksigner verify MyApp.apk
```

just change `/Users/adewale***/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools` to your build tools path.
Done

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same problem on `windows 10`, I found `apksigner.jar` jar file in the following path:

```
%localappdata%\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\lib
```

I did copy the `.jar` file and paste it inside `platform-tools` folder inside Android sdk directory

Comment: thanks man, this saved me. there always should be someone who works with workarounds 

Comment: Thank you man after 22 hours finally found the solution.

Comment: This is the ANSWER because, the `apksigner.bat` is not required but `apksigner.jar` is. This file is a bit of an oddball because it has this ghostly bat file in the expected `bin` folder but the real `jar file resides in the lib folder!`

Answer (score 8):

On Windows 10 it should be under directory

```
 C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\
```

Note the AppData directory is by default hidden.
First make sure you installed Android SDK 24.0.3 or later.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use this command will work for sure **(For Windows)**

--Go to this directory

```
C:/Users/{UserName}/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.0/
```

--Type this command :

```
apksigner.bat verify {PathToApp/AppName}.apk
```

Full Example :

```
C:/Users/Surya/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.0/apksigner.bat verify C:/AndroidApp/test.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows I couldn't use apksigner even with build tools version 31.0.0.

finally used apksigner command with .bat postfix and it worked fine.

for example

```
 apksigner.bat verify AppName.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded command-line tools and haven't extracted "build-tools" folder yet then open cmd and go to folder's location where your SDKManager is present and then run the following command:

```
//sdkmanager build-tools verison number like following command

sdkmanager build-tools;31.0.0
```

"apksigner.jar" comes inside the build-tools\version number\lib folder.

After running the above command, set the path (where your apksigner.jar is present) in environemnt variable.

You can check list of build tools versions from following link:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools

Or simply you can run following command in the cmd:

```
sdkmanager --list
```

Answer (score 0):

just store this in path environment values: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\build-tools\32.0.0`