# 'apksigner' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android

I am trying to run:

```
apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.jks --out my-app-release.apk my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk
```

But I get the following error:

> 'apksigner' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find 'apksigner' executable to manually sign APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40004884/cant-find-apksigner-executable-to-manually-sign-apk)