# how to upload an android app bundle to google play

Tags: android, upload, google-play, store, android-app-bundle

I'm fairly new to the process of uploading the Android App Bundle to the Google Play store, thus, the ask for help is highly appreciated.

A bit of backstory, all the builds we've uploaded to the Google Play store have been .apk files. The way we did this was:

- Our developer (Third-party) would provide an **unsigned** .apk
- We would then run it through a script that would apply our keystore to sign it.
- After that, we would upload it to the store and distribute it accordingly (Testing or Production).

Now, with the .aab process is where i get lost. Our developer provided us with an **unsigned** .aab and when i upload it to the store, i get a "**The Android App Bundle was not signed.**" error message.

The process is set with "**Let Google manage and protect your app signing key (recommended)**" option. I've also tried with "**Use the same key as another app in this developer account**" but with the same outcome. Finally, the options for "**Export and upload a key from Java keystore**" and "**Export and upload a key (not using Java Keystore)**" are out of my knowledge.

Would someone be able to suggest what the best options to use is? and if you can provide some step-by-step instructions of the upload process?

Everything i find here doesn't really cover my scenario unless i missed something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can sign an apk manually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40004884/cant-find-apksigner-executable-to-manually-sign-apk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to sign the AAB before you upload it. Except you need to use `jarsigner` instead of `apksigner`.

The rest should remain the same unless you rely on the certificate of the app to use some 3p APIs.

Comment: Thank you very much. This did it for me. Jarsigned the build then selected "Export and upload a key from Java keystore" where I uploaded the zip required and it worked fine.